# Access data from variable having one row in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am using object of type `Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet` which I passed from the controller to a view. Code is given below:

`view/districts/index.php`:

```
foreach ($pk_province as $pname) 
{   
    $p_id = $this->escapeHtml($pname->id);
    $p_name = $this->escapeHtml($pname->p_name);     
}
```

`$pk_province` has single record. So I want to access data from it without loop. I tried `$p_name = $pk_province->p_name` but it gives me undefined variable `$d_name`.

Any suggestion please.

`var_dump($pk_province);` shows the following:

```
object(Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet)#344 (8) {
    ["allowedReturnTypes":protected]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(11) "arrayobject" 
        [1]=> string(5) "array" 
    } 
    ["arrayObjectPrototype":protected]=> object(Admin\Model\Provinces)#312 (3) { 
        ["id"]=> NULL 
        ["p_name"]=> NULL 
        ["inputFilter":protected]=> NULL 
    } 
    ["returnType":protected]=> string(11) "arrayobject"  
    ["buffer":protected]=> NULL 
    ["count":protected]=> int(1) 
    ["dataSource":protected]=> object(Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Result)#322 (9) {
        ["statementMode":protected]=> string(7) "forward" 
        ["fetchMode":protected]=> int(2) 
        ["resource":protected]=> object(PDOStatement)#316 (1) {
            ["queryString"]=> string(58) "SELECT `provinces`.* FROM `provinces` WHERE `id` = :where1" 
        } 
        ["options":protected]=> NULL 
        ["currentComplete":protected]=> bool(false) 
        ["currentData":protected]=> NULL 
        ["position":protected]=> int(-1) 
        ["generatedValue":protected]=> string(1) "0"  
        ["rowCount":protected]=> int(1) 
    } 
    ["fieldCount":protected]=> int(2) 
    ["position":protected]=> int(0) 
}
```

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($pk_province)`?

Comment: I edit the above question and added output of var_dump($pk_province)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `ResultSet` to an array using [the `ResultSet::toArray` method](https://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.4/classes/Zend.Db.ResultSet.ResultSet.html#method_toArray) and get the first row from your array:

```
$array = $resultSet->toArray();
$province = $array[0];
```

Or you can use [the `ResultSet::current` method](https://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.4/classes/Zend.Db.ResultSet.ResultSet.html#method_current) to collect the current row:

```
$province = $resultSet->current();
```